# Como ler na aplicação android um ficheiro CSV previamente embutido?

Tags: csv

Estou a ter dificuldades em conseguir realizar está parte , já segui todos os passos de diversos sites, chego ao fim e a aplicação lê o ficheiro.
Alguém sabe o que poderá estar a acontecer??

Comment: Melhore sua pergunta, acrescentando a parte do código onde você tem dificuldade para chegar ao resultado pretendido.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo à comunidade. Visto que é novo por aqui, recomendo que faça o [tour] e leia o guia de [ask]. Da maneira que está, sua pergunta não está suficientemente clara e está passível de fechamento. Você poderá [edit] sua pergunta adicionando mais detalhes do que fez - e do que não fez -, assim como colocar o código fonte relacionado ao problema; busque criar um [mcve] demonstrando a situação também. Fazendo isso, conseguirá manter a pergunta aberta e, principalmente, conseguirá ajuda mais fácil.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Leandro,

Encontrei este artigo que pode ser relevante:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499351/how-to-read-csv-file-in-android

O seguinte código será da resposta dada como correta:

```
public final List<String[]> readCsv(Context context) {
List<String[]> questionList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();

try {
InputStream csvStream = assetManager.open(CSV_PATH);
InputStreamReader csvStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(csvStream);
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(csvStreamReader);

String[] line;

// throw away the header
csvReader.readNext();

while ((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
questionList.add(line);
}

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

return questionList;

}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado colega e continuação de bom trabalho

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)

Comment: Já alterei o post, obrigado pela indicação, não tinha pensado no assunto.